# Model binding to an interface using default behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, parameters, model-binding

I'm trying to bind a controller action to an interface but still maintain the default binding behavior.

```
public class CoolClass : ISomeInterface
{
    public DoSomething {get;set;} // ISomeInterface
}

public class DosomethingController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(ISomeInterface model)
    {
        // do something with model which should be an instance of CoolClass
    }
}
```

The consumer of my service knows nothing of CoolClass so having them add "$type" to the JSON they are passing would be a hack in my opinion. I'd like to be able to handle it in the service. If I specify CoolClass as the action parameter it works fine.

I found a partial solution to my question here [Dependency injection for ASP.NET Web API action method parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950395/dependency-injection-for-asp-net-web-api-action-method-parameters) but there is a follow up issue. That solution does not resolve interface properties. See my example below:

IConcreteClass will be resolved, but ISubtype will not.

```
public class SubConcreteClass : ISubtype
{
    // properties
}

public class ConcreteClass : IConcreteClass
{
    public ISubtype Subtype {get;set;}
}
```

Once the media formatter sees that is can resolve the type in IConcreteClass, it then reads the entire stream. So I'm guessing there is no chance to resolve interface members.

Comment: For another alternative, check out my answer to a similar question [_here_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124189/can-i-pass-an-interface-based-object-to-an-mvc-4-webapi-post/22279204#22279204).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As I mentioned above, the interface parameters of the action method can be resolved using DI. But the interface members of that object need to be handled differently.

I created 2 types of JSON converters, a single entity type and a collection type, to decorate the interface properties.

Here's a class that needs to be resolved as an action interface parameter.

```
public class CreateEnvelopeModel : ICreateEnvelopeCommand
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(EntityModelConverter<CreateEmailModel, ICreateEmailCommand>))]
    public ICreateEmailCommand Email { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CollectionEntityConverter<CreateFormModel, ICreateFormCommand>))]
    public IList<ICreateFormCommand> Forms { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the controller action method

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostEnvelope(ICreateEnvelopeCommand model)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Here are the 2 JSON converters

```
public class EntityModelConverter<T, Tt> : JsonConverter where T : Tt
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(Tt));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value, typeof(T));
    }
}

public class CollectionEntityConverter<T, Tt> : JsonConverter where T : Tt
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(IList<Tt>));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        IList<Tt> items = serializer.Deserialize<List<T>>(reader).Cast<Tt>().ToList();
        return items;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value, typeof(IList<T>));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is beautifully simple and effective. Are there any drawbacks in using this versus custom model binding? Any thoughts on how to use something like this on a collection where the interface has multiple implementation classes (e.g. IAuto, Car:IAuto, Truck:IAuto)?